# How to format y values in a tool tip to show commas?

Tags: highcharts, formatting, tooltip, string-formatting

I am using HTML to display values in my shared tooltip. I am using html so as to align my numerical values for both my series to right. Not sure if there is any other way. But the number values in the tooltio appear to be seperated by decimal points. Is there a way to have comma seperated values in the tooltip. Something like (123,123,123) ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set it with the [`thousandsSep`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.thousandsSep). It defaults to `,` so you may have a different language setup that is forcing `.`.

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/n8V3H/ and hover over the highest point. Tooltip uses `blah` for thousands separator.